# Why is NPM calling Python with 2.x-only syntax?

Tags: python, npm

Whilst running `npm install`, I've run into an **invalid syntax error**. I am fully aware of HOW to fix it, however I don't know where to begin. I don't know where this issue is occurring, and why it is occurring.

```
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe 
-c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

Obviously, it should be `print("%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3])`, since I'm running v3.7.4. Does my `npm install` rely on a lower version of python? Do I need to temporarily downgrade my python? Thanks!

Comment: What specific piece of software are you `npm install`ing? (If it's a dependency that's trying to run this at install time, which specific one?)

Comment: ...if you've verified that this happens with every possible `npm`-distributed library, that moots the question, but the fact of that verification should be included in the question.

Comment: I was downloading some dependencies when I got this error. I also got the error trying to run `npm install mocha@^4.0.0` -- what I'm installing has outdated dependencies, I think

Comment: `npm` doesn't know what Python you are using; it's probably just picking up your default Python, but *assumes* it will be Python 2.

Comment: So DO I need to temporarily downgrade to 2.x for this to work? Is there some other workaround?

Comment: @chepner, ...right -- but does npm itself *care* what Python one is using? My expectation is that it's one of the libraries being installed that's doing this check, insofar as npm itself is only concerned with the javascript ecosystem.

Comment: @xupaii, ...can you turn up the log level to see exactly what's happening when the check runs? If it's a specific library being installed that runs it, then we can isolate the cause, and hand-install a patched version of that one library, remove it from the dependency chain if it isn't strictly needed, or otherwise take an appropriate remedial action.

Comment: Huh.. I've re-run it -- no longer getting this issue. However I must install a peer of mocha >=4 <=5

Comment: I can't install the latest mocha or mocha4.1 -- I think I throw in the towel haha

Comment: If you were on a UNIXlike, I'd suggest using Nix rather than npm -- one of its major design advantages is being able to give each process a PATH containing only the exact program versions it depends on, so you could have Python 2.x installed for purposes of this command while still keeping your Python 3.x in place for everything else -- but I don't know of any comparable toolchain for Windows.